# Python how to create a class that wraps any value

Tags: python

Let's say I have an `Entity` class:

```
class Entity(dict):
    pass

    def save(self):
        ...
```

I can wrap a dict object with `Entity(dict_obj)`

But is it possible to create a class that can wrap any type of objects, eg. int, list etc.

PS I have come up the following work around, it doesn't work on the more complex objects, but seems to work with basic ones, completely unsure if there are any gotchas, might get penalised with efficiency by creating the class every time, please let me know:

```
class EntityMixin(object):

    def save(self):
        ...

def get_entity(obj):
    class Entity(obj.__class__, EntityMixin):
        pass

    return Entity(obj)
```

Usage:

```
>>> a = get_entity(1) 
>>> a + 1
2
>>> b = get_entity('b')
>>> b.upper()
'B'
>>> c = get_entity([1,2])
>>> len(c)
2
>>> d = get_entity({'a':1})
>>> d['a']
1
>>> d = get_entity(map(lambda x : x, [1,2]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jlin/projects/django-rest-framework-queryset/rest_framework_queryset/entity.py", line 11, in get_entity
    return Entity(obj)
TypeError: map() must have at least two arguments.
```

Improve efficiency:

```
EntityClsCache = {}

class EntityMixin(object):

    def save(self):
        ...

def _get_entity_cls(obj):

    class Entity(obj.__class__, EntityMixin):
        pass

    return Entity

def get_entity(obj)
    cls = None
    try:
       cls = EntityClsCache[obj.__class__]
    except AttributeError:
       cls = _get_entity_cls(obj)
       EntityClsCache[obj.__class__] = cls
    return cls(obj)
```

Comment: What do you mean by wrapping? Is it building a set of handy methods upon built-in types? If yes, wouldn't it be more preferred to store the object being "wrapped" in a private field of your class instead of subclassing?

Comment: Reason being I want the wrapper class to be as transparent as possible, using __getattributes__ do not work with underscore underscore methods

Comment: You could have overloaded the `__getattribute__` of your class so that it would have proxied them to the inner object. Unless you give a better example of what wrapping is, this is the best I can come up with -- the question is still too vague to me.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, `__getattribute__` doesn't get called for `__methods__` right?

Comment: It doesn't and you shouldn't need that -- what I suggested initially was "store the initial object in a private field, in your class's methods, access the said object when necessary, make `__getattribute__` proxy access to anything not defined on your class to the object stored privately".

Comment: To be able to provide a helpful answer, it would be good to know the use case (or at least a typical use case) you have in mind - the answer provided by @a small orange seems pretty good, but apparently that's not satisfactory due to circumstances that aren't clear from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you propose looks elegant, but it lacks caching, as in, you'll construct a unique class every time `get_entity()` is called, even if types are all the same.

Python has metaclasses, which act as class factories. Given that metaclass' methods override these of **class,** not the instance, we can implement class caching:

```py
class EntityMixin(object):
    pass


class CachingFactory(type):
    __registry__ = {}

    # Instead of declaring an inner class,
    # we can also return type("Wrapper", (type_, EntityMixin), {}) right away,
    # which, however, looks more obscure
    def __makeclass(cls, type_):
        class Wrapper(type_, EntityMixin):
            pass

        return Wrapper

    # This is the simplest form of caching; for more realistic and less error-prone example,
    # better use a more unique/complex key, for example, tuple of `value`'s ancestors --
    # you can obtain them via type(value).__mro__
    def __call__(cls, value):
        t = type(value)
        typename = t.__name__
        if typename not in cls.__registry__:
            cls.__registry__[typename] = cls.__makeclass(t)
        return cls.__registry__[typename](value)


class Factory(object):
    __metaclass__ = CachingFactory
```

This way, `Factory(1)` performs `Factory.__call__(1)`, which is `CachingFactory.__call__(1)` (without metaclass, that'd be a constructor call instead, which would result in a class instance -- but we want to make a class first and only then instantiate it).

We can ensure that the objects created by `Factory` are the instances of the same class, which is crafted specifically for them at the first time:

```py
>>> type(Factory(map(lambda x: x, [1, 2]))) is type(Factory([1]))
True
>>> type(Factory("a")) is type(Factory("abc"))
True
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort, but using metaclass is a bit over complicated, given the number of class types to be used are quite limited, we can easily pre-register the known types via module attribute and cache on new types during run time.